# jquery rotating a wheel - smooth

Tags: jquery, rotation

please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yWGp8/

is there any way to avoid the shift when the 'click here' link is pressed repeatedly ?
disabling the link before the animation finishes is not an option as the wheel will rotate when a link in the menu is clicked and i cant block menu links just for the sake of the animation.

im using this jquery plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation
and for easing: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

http://jsfiddle.net/yWGp8/1/